# For a normal domain: $f \in (g) \iff \operatorname{ord}_\mathfrak p f \geq \operatorname{ord}_\mathfrak p g$ for all primes $\mathfrak p$ of height 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec} A$ be an integrally closed noetherian domain. I'm stuck showing the following equivalence for two elements $f, g \in A$:

> The elment $f$ is contained in the principal ideal $(g)$ if and only if for each prime ideal $\mathfrak p \subset A$ of height $\operatorname{ht} \mathfrak p = 1$, we have $\operatorname{ord}_\mathfrak p f \geq \operatorname{ord}_\mathfrak p g$.

Here $\ord_\mathfrak p$ is the valuation of the DVR $A_\mathfrak p$. Put in other words: $f$ is contained in $(g)$ if and only if $f \in g \cdot A_\mathfrak p$ for all primes $\mathfrak p$ of height $1$.

One direction is easy: If $f \in (g)$, we have $f = h g$ for some $h \in A$, and hence for any $\mathfrak p \subset A$ of height $1$,  $$\operatorname{ord}_\mathfrak p f = \ord_\mathfrak p(hg) = \ord_\mathfrak p h + \ord_\mathfrak p g \geq \ord_\mathfrak p g.$$

I'm not sure about the converse. Here is what I tried:

Pick any prime ideal $\mathfrak p_1$ of height $1$. Then by assumption, there are elements $h_1, s_1 \in A$, $s_1 \notin \mathfrak p_1$ with
$$s_1 f = h_1 g.$$
Then $\mathfrak p_1 \in D(s_1)$ . We may continue picking $\mathfrak p_i$ with additional elements $h_i$ and $s_i$ as above, satisfying $s_i f = h_i g$. Then, if at one point, all the $s_1, \dotsc, s_n$ generate the unit ideal, meaning that $\bigcup_i D(s_i) = \Spec A$, we have
$$f = 1 \cdot f = (\lambda_1 s_1 + \dotsb \lambda_n s_n)f = \lambda_1 h_1 g + \dotsb + \lambda_n h_n g,$$
hence $f$ is contained in the ideal $(g)$. However, its not clear to me why we should ever get $\bigcup_i D(s_i) = \Spec A$.

For this we would have look at maximal ideals $\mathfrak m \in \Spec A \setminus \bigcup_{i=0}^n D(s_i)$, and pick the next tuple $(\mathfrak p_{n+1}, h_{n+1}, s_{n+1})$ such that $\mathfrak m \in V(\mathfrak p_{n+1})$ and $s_{n+1} \notin \mathfrak m$. This would ensure $\mathfrak m \in D(s_{n+1})$, and so we get an increasing sequence
$$D(s_1) \subsetneq D(s_1) \cup D(s_2) \subsetneq \dotsb,$$
which would stabilize because $\Spec A$ is a noetherian topological space. Thus $\bigcup_i D(s_i) = \Spec A$. But I don't know how to find $(\mathfrak p_{n+1}, h_{n+1}, s_{n+1})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rephrase the converse: Show that $$A=\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p}|ht \mathfrak{p}=1} A_\mathfrak{p}$$

where the intersection is in the fraction field $K(A)$ of $A$.

Assuming the above statement $f/g\in A_\mathfrak{p}$ for all ht 1 prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$. Hence $f/g\in A$.

Now to see the claim: see Hartshorne, Chapter 2, Theorem 4.11A and references therein.

Comment: Thanks! I knew that equality $A = \bigcap A_{\mathfrak p}$, but didn't see how it's useful...